# checkbox input element doesn't vertically align

Tags: html, css, checkbox, vertical-alignment

I am creating a form with text, radio and checkbox inputs as well as labels.

```css
fieldset {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: .5em;
}

legend {
  color: #61f231;
  font-size: 85%;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 20em;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 1em .5em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

label.left_label {
  float: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

input {
  width: 20em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 1em .5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: auto;
  padding: 1em .5em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

br {
  clear: both;
}

input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 3px #61f231;
}
```

```html
<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" autofocus required><br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" required><br>
<label for="verify">Re-Type Password</label>
<input type="password" name="verify" id="verify" required><br>
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="hello1" id="hello_1"
       value="hello1"
       title="blah blah">
<label class="left_label" for="hello_1">hello 1</label>
```

As you can see the last input element is a checkbox and its formatting is to be a little different. I want it to be aligned with the text inputs above it. Therefore I put an empty label as the first element after the "verify" input.

However, for some reason the checkbox element does not vertically align in the middle (which is my desired result) (it is aligned at the top).

Also, If I place a text input instead of the empty label element then the checkbox does vertically align in the middle.

Can someone explain the reason for this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to checkbox

```
.middle
{
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this one you are expecting?

```css
fieldset {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: .5em;
}

legend {
  color: #61f231;
  font-size: 85%;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 20em;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 1em .5em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

label.left_label {
  float: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  width: 20em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 1em .5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: auto;
  padding: 1em .5em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

br {
  clear: both;
}

input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 3px #61f231;
}
.middle{
  margin-top: 1.2em;
  }
```

```html
<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" autofocus required><br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" required><br>
<label for="verify">Re-Type Password</label>
<input type="password" name="verify" id="verify" required><br>
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="hello1" class="middle" id="hello_1"
       value="hello1"
       title="blah blah">
<label class="left_label" for="hello_1">hello 1</label>
```